# Pytorch dataloader, too many threads, too much cpu memory allocation

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, dataloader

I'm training a model using PyTorch. To load the data, I'm using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. The data loader is using a custom database I've implemented. A strange problem has occurred, every time the second `for` in the following code executes, the number of threads/processes increases and a huge amount of memory is allocated

```py
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, opt.niter + opt.niter_decay + 1):
        epoch_start_time = time.time()
        if epoch != start_epoch:
            epoch_iter = epoch_iter % dataset_size
        for i, item in tqdm(enumerate(dataset, start=epoch_iter)):
```

I suspect the threads and memories of the previous iterators are not released after each `__iter__()` call to the data loader.
The allocated memory is close to the amount of memory allocated by the main thread/process when the threads are created. That is in the initial epoch the main thread is using 2GB of memory and so 2 threads of size 2GB are created. In the next epochs, 5GB of memory is allocated by the main thread and two 5GB threads are constructed (`num_workers` is 2). 
I suspect that `fork()` function copies most of the context to the new threads.

The following is the Activity monitor showing the processes created by python, `ZMQbg/1` are processes related to python.
[image]

My dataset used by the data loader has 100 sub-datasets, the `__getitem__` call randomly selects one (ignoring the `index`). (the sub-datasets are `AlignedDataset` from pix2pixHD GitHub repository):

Answer (score 1):

torch.utils.data.DataLoader prefetch 2*num_workers, so that you will always have data ready to send to the GPU/CPU, this could be the reason you see the memory increase

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html